# Windows suspending processes for no apparent reason

Tags: windows, windows-10, suspend, resource-monitor

I observed that some processes may get suspended by `Windows`. If this happens, they no longer run and appear frozen. I don't understand why they are getting suspended since I did not do it manually. Using `Resource Monitor` I can see suspended processes and resume them. How can I make sure that certain processes like `java.exe` (`OpenJDK`) are not being suspended when I e.g. update [`CLion`](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/) `IDE`? It makes it seem like the updater got stuck/crashed so it's irritating. After resuming, the process continues normally. The suspensions aren't totally random but they happen pretty consistently.

Any ideas what could be causing this and why?

Comment: I'm having this exact issue... Sometimes it suspends the Java application I'm developing, sometimes it suspends my Postgres database instance, and sometimes it suspends Chrome. It is unpredictable, recurring, and frustrating!

Answer (score 1):

"Suspended" just means that a process is currently "Ready" for execution, or that
it is "Blocked" while waiting for input from the user or from some process.
While it is in the suspended state, the process memory may be swapped out to save
RAM consumption.

This happens with many applications, most often UWP apps such as Photos and
Microsoft Edge, that Windows keeps ready for instant execution
(although this Windows feature is more suitable for small tablets rather than a desktop).

This Windows feature is mostly intended so that some selected Windows apps
will be started instantly without needing any initialization,
therefore giving the impression that Windows 10 is reacting very fast
(ie marketing).

As long as you have enough RAM, at any given time, the performance of these apps
will barely be affected once their execution is triggered.
Windows scheduling ensures that you won't feel the lag when switching processes,
as moving processes back and fourth from swap to RAM usually happens too fast
for human perception.

Comment: The problem here is the "started instantly" part... once these applications are suspended, they are STUCK and can't be used again until I reboot.

Comment: Please give some examples.

Comment: Java, Postgres, and Chrome.

Comment: (1) Are these programs asking for some input? (2) What antivirus/security software is installed? (3)Do you any RAM-optimization product installed (example Process Lasso)? (4) For Chrome specifically, does this happen in Incognito mode?

Comment: 1. No. 2. None. 3. No. 4. No I don't use Incognito mode.

Comment: The behavior you are observing is not normal - the normal case is covered in my answer. This is either caused by Windows corruption or some installed product. For Windows, try [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html) and `chkdsk` and also antivirus scans. For disabling/re-enabling startup products see [Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns). If all fails, perhaps [In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html) to reset Windows to a known state.